# Z-indexing ::before elements for a flex box ul

Tags: css

i have a flex box "ul" and for each "li" of the "ul" i have made a ::before pseudo element with a box shadow applied on it. i want to make it so that all the ::before elements are placed under all the "li's", so that all the shadows show under all the "li", otherwise, the shadow of the second "li" will overlap the background of the first "li".

i tried having a negative z-index on the ::before elements and a positive one on the "li"'s, but it doesn't work.

Comment: no z-index to li elements